# Return value of a process and comparison of the number

Tags: process, exit

I have a `val.py` python script that returns a negative number.

```
import sys
sys.exit(-1234)
```

When I run this bash script, I get the value `$?` as return value of 46 (not -1234).
Even when I tried to compare the value with `$? == 46` or `$? == "46"`, it doesn't work at all.

```
python val.py
echo $?

if [ $? == 46 ]; then
    echo "Match"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

- Q1 : Why the return value is not correctly stored in `$?`?
- Q2 : Why the $? == NUMBER comparison doesn't work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The status passed to `exit()` by a process is masked to a single byte, so it's limited to the range `[0-255]`. See the [`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exit.html) documentation:

> The value of status may be 0, EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE,  or any other value, though **only the least significant 8 bits (that is, status & 0377) shall be available to a waiting parent process**.

On two's complement implementations, `-1234d == 0x...ffffb2e`, and `0x2e == 46d`, so the result you are seeing is expected.

For you second question, you `if` statement is testing the exit status from `echo $?`, not the one from your python program.

Try:

```
python val.py
rc=$?
echo $rc
if [ $rc == 46 ] ; then
...
```

Comment: I would add that `$((-1234 & 255))` gives exactly 46.

Comment: Good point, added an piece about that.

Comment: `0377` is quite a strange way to write `255` or `0xff`!

Comment: Sometimes known as the "not a tty problem", because in the old days people would print out the errno, and then use the C function `strerror` that printed out what the error code meant, only to find it always said "not a tty", because `printf` set errno itself to that value.